# brew update: Error in terminal mac

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    Library/Contributions/brew_bash_completion.sh
    Library/Contributions/brew_fish_completion.fish
    Library/Contributions/brew_zsh_completion.zsh
    Library/Contributions/manpages/brew.1.md
        ...

    Library/Formula/dmtx-utils.rb
    Library/Formula/docbook-xsl.rb
    Library/Formula/dromeaudio.rb
    Library/Formula/dub.rb
    Library/Formula/dvorak7min.rb
    Library/Formula/dyld-headers.rb
    Library/Formula/dylibbundler.rb
    Library/For
Aborting
Error: Failure while executing: git pull -q origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: Brew update not happening. Sorry if it wasn't clear enough.

Comment: You have local changes in your brew files. The error message is completely obvious in this. Did something change these files?

Comment: No i have not made any changes.

Comment: I am presently trying to update GIT. Its updating right now. If that may be a problem.

Comment: updating GIT has not worked either. Same error.

Comment: reinstalling homebrew solved the problem. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this a few times and don't know what causes it; but if you're sure you haven't made any modifications to those files that you want to save, you can go into /usr/local (or wherever you keep the Homebrew installation) and type `git reset --hard HEAD`. Then try updating again.

Comment: I reinstalled homebrew and its working now. I also reinstalled git like i said. Its cleared the way for me to install mongodb. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting files and reinstalling HOMEBREW solved the problem.

Comment: yikes; a less drastic method would be preferred.